# set rails fog gem application.yml keys for development environment

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5, fog, figaro-ruby

I'm using paperclip, fog, figaro gems to upload images to amazon S3. In production works fine as I introduced the env variables in heroku by hand.

But in development, it is suposed to use the env from the aplication.yml file (added to .gitignore). It is not using this file, as in development the ENV[] placed in application.yml do not exist.

I followed several tutorial for this, and in all of them I understand that the ENV[] introduced in applicaction.yml should be used. Am I wrong? Am I missing something? Do I need something else? I read that I can introduce the ENV[] by hand typing export, but I need to know if it is not enough to write them down at application.yml

```
#config/application.yml    
MAPS_API_KEY: 1234googlemapapikey56788

SECRET_KEY_BASE: ab1234567longkeyy2979127401411124
AWS_ACCES_KEY_ID: ACCESSKEYID1234567
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: SECRETKEY123456788/jaa\12345
AWS_REGION: eu-west-1
S3_HOST_NAME: s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

development:
  FOG_DIRECTORY: example-dev
  S3_BUCKET_NAME: example-dev
production:
  FOG_DIRECTORY: example-production
  S3_BUCKET_NAME: example-production
```

in development and production I use the same code:

```
#config/environments/development.rb && config/environments/production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
storage: :s3,
s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
```

In production works fine, and in development I get errors like:
development.rb:54:in `fetch': key not found: "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" (KeyError)

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `config/application.yml` you list above has a typo.

The key you want is `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, but the copied file uses `AWS_ACCES_KEY_ID` (where `access` is missing the second `s`).

I suspect that should get things working for you again.